# How to print bmp in specific place

Tags: assembly, bmp, emu8086

I'm trying to print a small photo 10*10 pixels in a specific place, but I don't know how to do it. I know how to print a 320*200 photo.

Comment: Can you show us how you would print a 320x200 photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using *nested loops*. The outer loop iterates over the y-position and the inner loop iterates over the x-position.

Suppose you want to place the 10x10 photo at (50,35) (upper left corner):

```
    mov si, ... ; Address of your photo data (256 colors)
    mov bh, 0   ; Display page
    mov dx, 35  ; Y
outerLoop:
    mov cx, 50  ; X
innerLoop:
    lodsb       ; Fetch pixel color from stored photo
    mov ah, 0Ch ; BIOS.WritePixel
    int 10h
    inc cx      ; Next X
    cmp cx, 50+10
    jb  innerLoop
    inc dx      ; Next Y
    cmp dx, 35+10
    jb  outerLoop
```